# Falling spool acceleration explanation

Tags: rotational-kinematics

In this example both spools A and B have the same downward acceleration. Why would the net downward force on Spool A be the same as for Spool B despite having more total kinetic energy?

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 1):

The net vertical force on the spools is the same because the tension upward is the same for both, and the weight downward is the same for both.

This is consistent with the difference in the kinetic energy because, the work done by gravity is the same for both, but the work done by the tension is not the same for both.